# SQLite: Database location or iosDatabaseLocation value is now mandatory in openDatabase call

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am using SQLite plugin for my ionic application for both android and iOS

Plugin: cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git

ionic version: 2.1.18

cordova version: 6.4.0

node version: 4.5.0

Here is my code to open and create database

```
var db;
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "test.db", iosDatabaseLocation:'default'});
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OfflineData (id integer primary key, imageUrl text, videoUrl text, head text, title text, descr text)");
```

But I am getting an issue while running this in my android device like

```
ionic.bundle.min.js:150 Error: Database location or iosDatabaseLocation value is now mandatory in openDatabase call
at newSQLError (plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:26)
at Object.<anonymous> (plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:565)
at Object.openDatabase (plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:59)
at Object.openDB (ng-cordova.js:5176)
```

Can any one help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are only specifying the iOS location, but are running on Android.

You need to detect which platform you are running on (using Ionic's `Platform` class) and use the `location` property for Android and `iosDatabaseLocation` for iOS.